# LaTeX lstlisting underlined

Tags: latex, lstlisting

Is there an easy way to have the complete code in a `lstlisting` environment underlined?
My current solution looks like this, but I'm not really happy with it.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
   $\ul{if(gt(x1, 0)) then} $
   ...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: you mean you don't want to \underline every line in the listing?

Comment: yes, i don't want to use the math env on every line and underline each line separately.

Answer (score 1):

According to page 5 in the user guide ([found here](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)):

```
\lstset{keywordstyle=\underbar}
```

Comment: Thats only working for keywords. But I'm not using any special syntax, so I have no keywords. I want the complete code to be underlined.

I tried \lstset{basicstyle=\underbar} , but that's also not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to underline the entire line (and not only the keywords), the best solution I can come up with is to do something along the lines below:

```
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\lstul}[1]{\underline{\mbox{\tt #1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
  $\lstul{if condition}$
      $\lstul{statement 1}$
  $\lstul{statement 2}$
  ...
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That solution is not much different to mine I posted in my question, except I named the command \ul and not \lstul .

Comment: Sure. I wasn't sure what you didn't like with it, so I assumed that it was the italicized math-font that disturbed you, which can be solved with the \mbox.

Comment: It makes the code look confusing. And you can not include the code from an external file :/

Comment: good points. Another point: Doesn't underlined code look ugly? :) I would much rather read the standard listing-formatting. What language is it that you're type-setting? Is it pseudo code? Could you post the actual listing-content in your question perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look very good, but I have to format it in this style, because it is for a course at university.

Comment: Then I wouldn't bother getting the latex nice either... :-]

Comment: It's not the question, if the latex code looks nice or not. It's not very comfortable to write a longer piece of code. Is there no way to achieve something similar with basicstyle?